# How to determine the Git Tag value in Azure DevOps?

Tags: git, github, azure-devops

I'm trying to figure out how to get the `tag` value when some code is tagged, in GitHub. (eg -> GitHub repo -> releases -> create a new release).

For example, I'm trying to set the `Build Version` based on the Git tag value.

```
steps:

- script: ##vso[area.action Build.BuildNumber=value;]Build.BuildNumber
  displayName: 'Setting the build number based on a Tag or not.'
  condition: and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/'))
```

So in the above `step` I'm trying to say:

- given a tag has been pushed
- get the tab value (eg. v1.2.3)
- set the environment variable `Build.BuildNumber` to this tag value.

So now all the other steps can access `Build.BuildNumber` which will be `v1.2.3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, you are not able to overwrite the build-in variables from within the build process. However you can simply work around this by defining a variable yourself.

I set this up as follows:

Setup a variable in the build definition, so i use the build.buildnumber by default
[image]

And added this step:

```
- powershell: |
   $ver = $env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH.remove(0, 10)
   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Version]$ver"
  displayName: 'Update version to Tag'
  condition: and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/'))
```

From that point on you can reference the 'Version' variable whenever you need the build version.

Comment: OF COURSE! Answer's feel so easy, once you get the answer. Doh. Works great - ta!